# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with recursive initialization of a static member

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, language-lawyer, static-members

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
struct foo
 { static std::size_t value; };

template <>
std::size_t foo<0>::value = 0u;

template <size_t N>
std::size_t foo<N>::value = 1u + foo<N - 1u>::value;

int main()
 {
   std::cout
      << foo<3u>::value << ' '
      << foo<2u>::value << ' '
      << foo<1u>::value << ' '
      << foo<0u>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

where the static member `value` of the template struct `foo` is recursively initialized, I get different outputs from g++:

```
3 2 1 0
```

and from clang++:

```
1 1 1 0
```

So seem that g++ initializes `foo<N>::value` recursively using the initialized value of `foo<N-1u>::value` where clang++ uses zero for `foo<N-1u>::value`.

Two questions:

1. is the preceding code legit or is it Undefined Behavior in some way?
2. if the preceding code is legit, who's right: g++ or clang++?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is unspecified. Both compilers are right.

Here are the relevant pieces from [cppreference "initialization"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization).

## Static initialization

> For all other non-local static and thread-local variables, Zero initialization takes place

So for all these variables, they are zero when the program loads. Then:

## Dynamic initialization

> **After all static initialization is completed**, dynamic initialization of non-local variables occurs in the following
>   situations:
>
> 1) Unordered dynamic initialization, which applies only to
>   (static/thread-local) class template static data members and ... that aren't explicitly specialized.

And these variables match the criteria. And then it says:

> Initialization of such static variables is indeterminately sequenced
>   with respect to all other dynamic initialization ....

Which means that any sequence of initialization is fine. Both compilers are correct.

To avoid the issue use `constexpr` to force a "constant initialization" instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is **Unspecified**.

You are using a **construct** where you reference a variable definition onto itself - perhaps somewhat analogue to saying `int i = i-1`. In clang case, it is just using the generic template definition

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct foo
  { static std::size_t value; };//without specialization this will be ZERO initialized
```

because it hasn't *seen* 'itself' like normal template class or function would (as opposed to gcc case).

To sum up:

1) Legit

2) Unspecified

To avoid issues use [constexpr](/questions/tagged/constexpr) and specialize the class template instead.

Comment: *"construct where you reference a variable onto itself"* I disagree. `foo<N>::value` and `foo<N-1>::value` are different variables.

Comment: Compare it to a function taking one argument - are foo(N) and foo(N-1) two different functions ?

Comment: `foo(N)` and `foo(N-1)` are the same, but `foo<N>()` and `foo<N-1>()` would be different.

Comment: Which is why I wrote "a construct" - feel free to clarify my answer though - I know it wasn't the greatest for 'correctness'

Comment: @darune The issue with the answer is that "itself"-ness doesn't really come into it. Absent any phrasing for specific case in the standard which says otherwise, `foo<3>` `foo<2>` and `foo<1>` are different types, just like `foo_3`, `foo_2` and `foo_1` would be. As I understand it, the template is a bit of a red herring: you'd (theoretically) have exactly the same sort of issues if you manually unrolled the templates into `foo_3`, etc. (On a standards level, at least - the compilers might treat them differently.)

Comment: @R.M. I agree with most of the comment, just not the unrolling - not fully. Conceptually I agree with it, but disagree on the effects of unrolling on init order. Global variables, or fully specialized templates, have a well defined in the translation unit they are defined in: by the definition order. In the code of the OP there is no order, while unrolling-order implies initialization order.