# Can static and dynamic template initialization be interleaved?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

As I understand it, given the following code:

```
template<int N> 
int i = i<N - 1> + i<N - 1>;  // primary variable template

template<> int i<0> = 1;      // and explicit specialization
```

the following program must return 2:

```
int main () { return i<1>; }
```

but this program can return 0 or 4:

```
int main () { return i<2>; }
```

since evaluating the instantiation of `i<2>` gives:

```
int i<2> = i<1> + i<1>;       // generated by the compiler
```

Here, since `i<1>` is only implicitly instantiated, the compiler can use either the statically initialized value of `i<1>`, which is `0`, or the dynamically initialized value, which is `2`.

Here's a [comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/RBVvp5) of different compilers giving different outputs (clang returns 0, gcc returns 4).

The question is - can this program return 2?

```
int main () { return i<2>; }
```

i.e. in the initialization of `i<2>`, can different initializations be used for the different uses of `i<1>`? Can the program return some other value entirely?

Comment: "*the statically initialized value of `i<1>`, which is 0*" - where do you get 0 from? You yourself said just above that statement that `i<1>` must be 2 instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau From [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#3). Also, in the first example, `i<1>` must be dynamically initialized, since it is used. But in the second program `i<1>` is not explicitly used, so the statically initialized version could be used. Edited the question a bit, hope that helps.

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would cause zero initialization as described in that article

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fair enough. I'm not saying my interpretation is definitely right. What about the clang output in the link? Do you think that's a bug then?

Comment: I don't know, because I can't see the output on that link right now. I'm on a phone right now, and that site is horrible for mobile

Comment: @RemyLebeau aah, no worries. clang prints 0. I can believe that's a bug, but then I'd like a language lawyer explanation of why clang must output 4, as you say it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know from [Recursive computation using variable templates - gcc vs clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234931/recursive-computation-using-variable-templates-gcc-vs-clang) that the dynamic initializations of `i<1>` and `i<2>` are indeterminately sequenced. Indeterminately sequenced evaluations can't interleave (overlap):

> Evaluations *A* and *B* are [*indeterminately sequenced*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#def:indeterminately_sequenced) when either *A* is sequenced before *B* or *B* is sequenced before *A*, but it is unspecified which. [ Note: Indeterminately sequenced evaluations cannot overlap, but either could be executed first.  — end note ]

So in the dynamic initialization of `int i<2> = i<1> + i<1>;`, either the static or the dynamic value of `i<1>` is used for both summands, depending on whether the dynamic initialization of `i<1>` has already happened.

Answer (score -2):

> the statically initialized value of `i<1>`, which is 0

Where do you get 0 from? You yourself said just above that statement that `i<1>` must be 2.

So, given:
`i<0>` = `1`
And:
`i<1>` = `i<0> + i<0>` = `1 + 1` = `2`
And:
`i<2>` = `i<1> + i<1>`
Then:
`i<2>` = `2 + 2` = `4`

It can't be anything other than 4.